# Why is my code giving me an AttributeError?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to iterate through a couple levels of html to retrieve links associated with legislation. However, once I reach the 2nd level of links, instead of retrieving a list of links associated with individual bills, I am getting the error:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
> File "C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\ilgascrapetest1.py", line 14, in 
> if href.startswith('/legislation/BillStatus.asp?'):
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

This is the code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/default.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the House Bills section
house_bills = soup.find('a', {"name": "h_bills"}).parent

# Iterate through all links in the House Bills section
for link in house_bills.find_all('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if href.startswith('/legislation/BillStatus.asp?'):
        bill_url = url + href
        bill_response = requests.get(bill_url)
        bill_soup = BeautifulSoup(bill_response.content, 'html.parser')

        # Find the table cell with width
        td = bill_soup.find('td', {'width': '100%'})
        
        # Iterate through all the <li> elements in table
        for li in td.find_all('li'):
            print(li.text)
```

I am able to retrieve the list of links from the ["House Bills" table](https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/default.asp) in the Html on the first page and iterate through that, but within the next level that [give a list of links to individual bills](https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/grplist.asp?num1=1&num2=100&DocTypeID=HB&GA=103&SessionId=112) I get the error instead of bill links from HB0001 to HB4042. Why am I getting this error

Comment: That means `href` is `None`, which means `link.get('href')` is returning `None`; likey indicating that that element doesn't have that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `<a>` elements on this site that have no `href`, so `link.get('href')` will return `None` in this cases. You can't call `startswith()` on `None`, so you have to add a check whether or not `href` is `None`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/default.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the House Bills section
house_bills = soup.find('a', {"name": "h_bills"}).parent

# Iterate through all links in the House Bills section
for link in house_bills.find_all('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not href:
        continue  # Ignore links without href
    if href.startswith('/legislation/BillStatus.asp?'):
        bill_url = url + href
        bill_response = requests.get(bill_url)
        bill_soup = BeautifulSoup(bill_response.content, 'html.parser')

        # Find the table cell with width
        td = bill_soup.find('td', {'width': '100%'})
        
        # Iterate through all the <li> elements in table
        for li in td.find_all('li'):
            print(li.text)
```

Also, you have confused the urls: first, you need to open "grplist.asp", then the links start with "BillStatus.asp". To access only the links in the house bills section, you need to select the `div` after the `a` with the name `h_bills`, not it's parent. I also changed your code so that `bill_url` isn't built from the full url including "/default.asp" any more.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/default.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the House Bills section (next div after a with name "h_bills")
house_bills = soup.find('a', {"name": "h_bills"}).find_next_sibling("div")

# Iterate through all links in the House Bills section
for link in house_bills.find_all('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not href:
        continue  # Ignore links without href

    if href.startswith('grplist.asp?'):
        bill_url = "https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/" + href

        bill_response = requests.get(bill_url)
        if bill_response.status_code != 200:  # Prevent crash when response is not valid
            continue

        bill_soup = BeautifulSoup(bill_response.content, 'html.parser')

        # Find the table cell with width
        td = bill_soup.find('td', {'width': '100%'})
        
        # Iterate through all the <li> elements in table
        for li in td.find_all('li'):
            print(li.text)
```

Comment: Okay, this got rid of the error, but now it won't print anything.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test my answer properly. Now it includes the working code to get all the links.

Comment: Ah, i didn't even think about the /default.asp as part of the url. Now it's working, thank you!